# MySQL nested query Lookup error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use nested query to avoid having to issue two different queries. My nested query is as shown below;

```
INSERT INTO roles (
   _id, 
   user_id,
   user_role)
VALUES (
((SELECT _id FROM roles ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1)+1), '454', 'USER')
```

But when I execute I get;

> Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: You can't specify target table
>   'roles' for update in FROM clause

Is there any work around to this query or I simply can't do insert and select on the same table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MySQL >= 4.0.14, you can use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO roles (
  _id, 
 user_id,
 user_role
)
SELECT _id + 1, '454', 'USER' FROM roles ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1
```

However, it looks as though you probably just want to make your `_id` column [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) and then don't provide any value for it.  MySQL will do the rest:

```
ALTER TABLE roles MODIFY _id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
INSERT INTO roles (user_id, user_role) VALUES (454, 'USER');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO roles 
SELECT _id+1,'454', 'USER' FROM roles ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1
```